# Incompatiblity mathdesign and sansmathfonts

Tags: fonts

I'd like to use in a same document the Bitstream Charter serif font (as default) and *some* sans serif font that has small caps. I tried to use `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` in combination with `\usepackage[notmath]{sansmathfonts}`, but it does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[notmath]{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
This is \textsc{small caps}. And {\sffamily\textsc{sans serif small caps}}.
\end{document}
```

1. With the example above, I get no sans serif small caps and the following in the log:

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/xcmss/m/fsc' undefined
   (Font)              using `T1/xcmss/m/n' instead on input line 8.
   ```
2. If I comment the `sansmathfonts` package, I still get no sans serif small caps and the following in the log:

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/fsc' undefined
   (Font)              using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 8.
   ```
3. Finally, if I comment the `mathdesign` package, I get sans serif small caps.

How may I achieve my goal? There's probably a lot that I do not understand about LaTeX font managements. I add that I would prefer a solution that uses pdfTeX rather than {Xe|Lua|...}TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mathdesign` package with the `charter` option will turn on the `expert` option, which is a too-clever-by-half workaround for some non-standard font naming schemes from the ’90s.  It is no longer needed: both free versions of Charter that ship with CTAN use standard LaTeX font-naming conventions.  The authors did not, unfortunately, provide any way to turn this option off.  It redefines small caps to use the NFSS shape `fsc` instead of `sc`.  Every LaTeX font calls small caps `sc`, not `fsc`, so small caps break.

The easiest fix is to load the free `XCharter` as your main font over `mathdesign`.  This will load `fontaxes` and replace the broken definitions of `\scshape` and `\textsc` with ones that work.  You can then load your sans-serif font of choice.  Here, I used Linux Biolinum.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[type1]{biolinum}

\begin{document}
This is \textsc{small caps}.
And {\sffamily\textsc{sans serif small caps}}.
\[x = -b \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: XCharter/Biolinum/MathDesign sample]

Similarly, you can load `erewhon` after `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}` or `garamondx` after `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`, all of which provide working small-caps and oldstyle numbers.

You can also enable small-caps for other font families with

```
\renewcommand\scdefault{sc}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!